# Linux: alias, PATH and HOME variables

Tags: linux

I'm learning a bit about linux and I was wondering if someone could show me how to create an alias view that prints the value of the PATH and HOME variables. The answer to this I would say is something like this:

```bash
function path(){
old=$IFS
IFS=:
printf "%s\n" $PATH
IFS=$old
}
```

And no, it's not a homework, it's a type of training task in the book Linux Command Line and Shell Scripting Bible**

Comment: For a useful view of $PATH, try `echo $PATH | tr ":" "\n" | sort`

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned an alias, so these would work:

```
alias home='printf "%s\n" "$HOME"'
alias path='printf "%s\n" "$PATH"'
```

Note that it is pretty much *always* a good idea to double quote variables in a *nix shell. It prevents the kinds of expansions that can get one in trouble. [You can read more here](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/quotingvar.html), though note that the article is Bash-centric.

Bash-centrism itself is something that gets folks in all kinds of trouble, especially in the world of containers. You never know when a strict POSIX shell like `Dash` might be interpreting your script when the shell is several layers of abstraction away (say an instrumentation tool that generates Dockerfiles dynamically and spins up multiple containers).

Comment: Now we have mentioned about alias. Is alias an internal or external command?

Comment: 'alias' is a [POSIX-specified](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_03_01) utility and is implemented as a shell built-in in at least most of the shells I've run across (bash, zsh, dash, ksh). It's discussed near the end of Chapter 5 of the book you mention, page 143 in the 2008 edition. But I only went there because you said 'alias' in your question. Did you mean something else?

Comment: If you would like to print the path with one component per line, you can use `printf "%b\n" "${PATH//:/\n}"`. The `//:\n` part replaces all `:` with `\n` in the string $PATH. To also sort the output—which will helpfully keep similar paths close together—use the approach suggested by MDeBusk.